# Why does setting UpdateSourceTrigger to Explicit still update the source?

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid, updatesourcetrigger

I have a WPF DataGrid with DataGridTextColumn

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Grouping" Binding="{Binding Value.GroupIndexPlusOne, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit, Converter={StaticResource StringToIntConverter}}" CanUserSort="False" Width="Auto" Utilities:IsReadOnlyDpAttachable.IsReadXOnly="{Binding Data.GroupingIsReadonly, Source={StaticResource proxy}}" />
```

Despite having set the UpdateSourceTrigger to Explicit in order to do the actual update from code, the moment I change the value in the column, the source still gets updated.

The source is a `ListCollectionView` wrapping a `ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<string, LayoutColumn>>`.

It makes no sense, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i m not sure you can really set the binding you want for a DataGridTextColumn. (sorry i cannot find 'proof'). Try with a TemplateColumn that you build on your own.

Comment: Hi Vincent. Thanks for your suggestion. I created a `DataGridTemplateColumn` with my UI element in and now I can control the binding correctly and update the source explicitly! Thanks!

Comment: Yes i once tried to change binding setting in a standard DataGridColumn with no success until i read somewhere it is not possible and switched to a custom DataGridTemplateColumn.  Glad it worked !